# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to serialize myclass

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-dataflow

I was using Google Dataflow and have encountered an error of

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to serialize ...
```

from SerializableUtils.class even I have serialVersionUID defined. I suspected the reason could be that I import non standard java library which is not listed on [JRE Class While List](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/jrewhitelist) . In my case I import javassist. I just want to confirm this is case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it turns out that whether or not the imported third party library is on the  JRE Class While List has nothing to do with this error. Dataflow runs on compute engine which is not restricted to the app engine white list. The culprit to my error is due to the introduction of a class member which is not serializable even though the the class itself implements Serializable interface.

Answer (score 0):

Serialization is about the **fields** in your classes - as this is the process of turning an existing Java object into a sequence of bytes; based on the *content* of that object.

An **import** within your Java source code is just a hint for the compiler to understand where names are coming from.

In other words: importing class A within source code for class B doesn't necessarily mean that class A will be serialized. You need to have a field of type A within B for that part!

Comment: in your example I do have a field of type A within B, but class A is not in the JRE Class White List, will that cause a problem?